# Arduino Yún shield password reset

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, arduino-yun

I'm using a Yún shield from Dragino with an Arduino Uno, but the default wifi password for the shield (which should be "dragino") isn't working.

I tried the wifi reset (holding down the reset button for 5 seconds) and a factory reset (holding down the reset button for 30 seconds) but the password still seems to be incorrect.

Is there any way I can reset the password?

Comment: Can you describe how you're determining that the password isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting via ethernet to 192.168.255.1 with root/root

The SSH access for Dragrove is:
IP: 192.168.255.1 on LAN port. If you want to connect to the Dragrove via WiFi, the IP should be 192.168.1.108.
Username: root
Password: root

http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Dragrove_-_Generic_gateway_for_internet_of_things

Answer (score 0):

Dragino is just the password for the first initial setup. You probably set a new password. Even if you reset the shield, it keeps your password. This happened to me to and then I put in my password and it worked.